# How to count occurrences of each year in Excel?

Tags: excel, date, countif

I want to count which cells have a specific year in their date/string.
I have a problem where my formula only works if it's a valid date, some cells have month or day missing or are totally blank.

Here are some examples of values I want to be able to count:

```
2002-07-?
2010-11-27
2009-10-21
2009-10-21
2004-12-20


2004-11-07
2010-11-?
2004-09-17
2000-?-?
2005-04-26
```

This is how I want the output to be:

```
Unknown 2
2000    1
2001    0
2002    1
2003    0
2004    3
2005    1
2006    0
2007    0
2008    0
2009    2
2010    2
```

If I use =COUNTIF(A1:A12;"2000*") I only get those cells which are strings. Is there a way I could count both dates and strings?

Comment: What about summing your dates formula and string formula?

Comment: How? Do I need to have a COUNTIF for date ranges and an COUNTIF for string values?

Comment: Yes, you would. `=COUNTIF(...) + COUNTIF(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a helper column and use the following formula to extract the year:

```
=IF(ISTEXT(A1);LEFT(A1;4);TEXT(A1;"YYYY"))
```

Then use your existing `=COUNTIF()` formula but without the wildcard `*` argument:

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A12;"2000")
```

Comment: I changed it to this, =IF(ISTEXT(A1);LEFT(A1;4);YEAR(A1)), and now it works :)

Comment: Of course, no need to format the year if it's already a valid date - d'oh! I'll update my answer to use the correct regional delimiter too.

Comment: Is there a reason to why you used "," instead of ";" as a delimiter? My Excel does not accept ",".

Comment: Yes, it's because I'm in the UK! the delimiter varies by region - so for example in the UK and USA we use `,` whereas many European regions use `;` also - it's only worksheet functions that use different delimiters, VBA uses `,` globally.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't got Excel to hand to test this, but I believe you can have another column that converts the value to text- I think it's `=TEXT(A1,"<format>")`, then just do your 'countif' on that.

EDIT: Forgot about the second argument. I'm surprised it didn't work with the 'yyyy' argument though.

Comment: If I use =TEXT(A1) I get an error, "to few arguments" and if I use =YEAR(A1) it does not handle "broken" date values. I've also tried =TEXT(A1;"yyyy") with no success.

Comment: the `=TEXT()` formula requires an output format in addition to a cell reference e.g. `=TEXT(A1,"@")`